# Do you know a GUI designer for YUI or for any other rich javascript library?

Tags: jquery, yui, gui-designer

The question says it all... We are shopping for a a rich javascript library and are about to choose YUI.
The issue of (non)existence of a GUI designer will strongly influence our choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [YUI CSS Grid Builder](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/builder/) cover what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Andy,

Daniel's answer is a good one for YUI CSS Grids. There is no wysiswyg editor that supports YUI widgets afaik, but this article might be of interest if you're a Dreamweaver CS4 user:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/using_yui_widgets.html

YUI's founder, Thomas Sha, did a lot of work to make YUI's widget's more accessible to Dreamweaver users.

Aptana has also done a lot of work to make sure that all the big JS kits are well supported.  They have a good YUI plugin for 2.6.0 and are working on the 2.7.0 update:

http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/10/28/aptana/

-Eric